# In VS 2010, "Format document" command (ie: Ctrl-k, Ctrl-d) swap tabs to spaces although set reverse in options

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tabs, formatting, spaces

If you use the "Format Document" command (ie: Ctrl-k, Ctrl-d) in Visual Studio 2010, the final result is a document where all of the tabs are swapped with spaces.

All that happens although I have set `Tools-Options-Text Editor-C#-Tabs` to:
`<Smart, 4, 4, Keep tabs>`

Comment: Do you have ReSharper installed? Because the ReSharper options override the Visual Studio settings on that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my bug.

It was with all my XAML file that I had my problems. I just realised that there is 2 differents way to fix my bug:

- Set the "Tabs" option for general document (if you haven't modify the XAML "Tabs" option).
- Set the "Tabs" options directly in the XAML option section.

Thanks
Eric